# How to read json or xml file using java servlets?

Tags: java, xml, json, servlets, javabeans

I am using NetBeans and I am going to create a web based app which processes any xml and json file according to some tools. Until now, I ve created a basic site using html and I also have some java code written in javabeans. 
I would like to ask you what do you think is the best way to read and process an xml or json file through java servlets? How can I pass the file(which the user chooses, to the side where further process can be done). I ve read that  HTTPClient class is a good way, however i am not sure if this is the best.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Apache Commons FileUpload library to handle the multipart request. A multipart request is what you receive when a form with a file element is posted to a servlet.

For example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

(...)

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            handleMultiPartContent(request);
        }
    }

    private void handleMultiPartContent(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        upload.setFileSizeMax(2097152); // 2 Mb
        try {
            FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    File tempFile = saveFile(item);
                    // process the file
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileUploadException e) {
            LOG.debug("Error uploading file", e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.debug("Error uploading file", e);
        }
    }

    private File saveFile(FileItemStream item) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = item.openStream();
            File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("tmp_upload", null);
            tmpFile.deleteOnExit();
            out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
            long bytes = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
                bytes += len;
            }
            LOG.debug(String.format("Saved %s bytes to %s ", bytes, tmpFile.getCanonicalPath()));
            return tmpFile;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            LOG.debug("Could not save file", e);
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof FileSizeLimitExceededException) {
                LOG.debug("File too large", e);
            }
            else {
                LOG.debug("Technical error", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.debug("Could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

This uploads the file and saves it as a temporary file on the server's harddisk. You can then do with the file what is needed.

Especially for very large files a better approach might be to skip the saving and process the InputStream directly. You need a suitable XML library for this (for example Stax) which can handle streams directly.

EDIT: the action attribute of your form should match the url-pattern of your servlet-mapping.

Example HTML:

```
<form action="upload" ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data' method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="user_file" accept="text/xml">
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

Example web.xml snippet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileReaderServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.application.FileReaderServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileReaderServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks! I use this code to my servlet, but it actually does nothing. I am new to this area and I guess something is missing from what i ve done. In JSP file I got the html code.The form which communicates with the servlet is as follows :

  <form action="FileReaderServlet" ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'    method="POST">
   <input type="file" name="user_file" accept="text/xml">   
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
As I read, when I use the name of servlet in the 'action' part,then the JSP file is connected with this servlet and it executes the Post method!

Comment: I cant really see where is the problem. Is like the validate button has no action on it, it just done nothing.At least nothing that is obvious. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have your servlet defined and mapped in web.xml?

Comment: Oh yean now I see, yes I correct it and now it works, I also add some extra things on the servlet! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to create a project without the web.xml file? Before to correct it, i had no xml file and no errors appeared.

Comment: 'A project' - yes. A J2EE web application - not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either HttpClient provided by apache (or) Sun provided HttpURLClient, both are good APIs. If you opt for apache you need to install extra Jars.

Apache HttpClient has couple of extra methods comparing with Sun provided one.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try thr one provided bt apache. I find some jars needed and I install them, now trying put them all together.